# python function Print to stdOut on many files

Tags: python

What would be the fastest way. I need to change

```
print('My text')
```

to

```
sys.stdout.write('My text')
 
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Point here is to have my application from .NET retrieve the console logs.
I have to much scripts to go over every one and change from print to sys.stdout....

Comment: using functools:
new_print = functools.partial(print, file=sys.stdout)

Comment: It sounds like you really just want the `-u` option to suppress buffering on standard output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

print function has builtin file and flush parameters

```
print("My text", file=sys.stdout, flush=Flase)
```

You can change it as you wish

Another way is

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open('file', 'w')
print('My text')
# all the other code #
sys.stdout.close()
```

also as @Stefano stated at comments you can create new function for this task

```
import sys

def my_print(text):
    print(text, file=file_path, flush=True)
```

Comment: Any way to set the print function to has that as default parameters ??
I.E just say `print('My text')` ?

Comment: It would be: `def print_and_log(my_text): print(my_text, file=sys.stdout, flush=Flase)`.  Then you can use that function instead the builtin `print`. Otherwise set an object `config = {'file':sys.stdout, 'flush':False}` and then use `print('My text', **config)`.

Comment: `print` already defaults to `sys.stdout`.